# Is anything real?

Tags: metaphysics

What if everything were fake? We are not real. We are all figments of the imagination of a single person's mind generating all the countless different minds with different worlds and different universes?

Comment: Definition of real? Well, in your case the person whose imagination products we are, is real.

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing if I misrepresented your position. Welcome to Philosophy!

Comment: Just to point it out the usage of the terms "fake", "real", ect is not clear maybe it would be good clarifing those. About the Question: if "everything" is "fake" the "mind" generating all the other minds is also fake. However if every "mind" is fake theres no reason why one should endorse a specifc structure. Meaning theres no reason to prefer one mind creating others over some minds creating others or no minds creating others. Additionaly I think "fake" is problematic term and would suggest calling it virtual since fake under some interpretations implies intentionality and/or conciousness.

Comment: Welcome to Absolute Idealism, or something close to it. . .

Comment: Nothing is real. [Change My Mind]

Comment: Everything is real. [Change My Mind]

Comment: Try not paying your tax... See how long it takes for reality to present itself. We might not know exactly what reality is.. whether it's a dream.. a simulation.. or something else... But denying it's existance is something we can't do in honesty.

Comment: @Richard - Quite so, but we can question what we mean by 'existence', and whether it means the same as 'real'. The distinction made in the perennial philosophy is between what exists and what is real. Hence Bradley's 'Appearance and Reality'. The assumption that existence and reality are the same thing renders metaphysics impossible since existence can have no source.     .

Comment: @PeterJ For me 'the physics' which became 'science' is the correct branch of philosophy in which to answer questions about the exact nature of reality.
Metaphysics IMO should always be keeping one eye on physics.
There are a lot of people who see a clear division between science and philosophy and ask questions for which 'we' already have good answers.
But as you know, I don't think Science has answers for the important metaphysical questions: What is consciousness? How did it all begin?
I don't understand your argument. Why would existence=reality mean existence can have no source?

Comment: @Richard. It would no use explain existence as arising from something that exists, This is simple logic. As you suggest, metaphysicians take physics for granted and never argue with it, Science cannot answer metaphysical questions because they are metaphysical. Science cannot find consciousness and has no clue about how it all began. These are metaphysical issues and they cannot be addressed by the empirical sciences. Metaphysics exists for a reason.  .

Comment: @PeterJ Yes I see your point. And I agree that Science currently doesn't explain that well at all. But that argument works for all ideas of existence. For example God is given as existing a-priori.
I absolutely accept that metaphysics poses valid questions. I think my point is that asking whether 'anything is real' is denying our own thoughts exist isn't it? I mean clearly our thoughts are real.

Comment: @Richard - Yes, we agree that something must be real, The question is  - What? What you say about God is correct. Because we have the idea that existence is fundamental we are forced to invent a creator God to explain existence, or a miracle if we're a materialist, or a pile of turtles or somesuch. This is why it does not work to assume that existence is fundamental or that reality is the same as existence, Introducing a commonplace Christian-style God just.pushes the problem back a step.   .

Comment: @PeterJ There is beauty in the standard scientific argument that there was no 'before', since time itself was created at the start of the universe. The problem is it's almost too neat. Our brains simply reject it, as if we're so hardwired into causality that we simply cannot imagine any significant event not having a significant cause. For years I accepted this as part of the human condition. We're just built that way. But like Penrose I've grown dissatisfied with that argument. Penrose however just added a universe before ours, and then turtles all the way down. That is even less satisfactory

Comment: @Richard - I think you'd like the perennial view. It does not suffer from these inadequacies. It disposes of the 'first cause' problem without need for turtles or creator gods and says that the human condition allows us to understand our origin and source. It just ain't easy.

Comment: Why would being an ideal construct—ie. a figment—be any less real or any less valid of an ontological source than being a material construct? Idealism is not a belief that nothing is real but only a belief about what the source of reality /really/ is.

Comment: The axiom of choice states that for any set of nonempty sets, there is a function that assigns to each of those sets one of its members. You may thing the axiom of choice is obviously true. It turns out that that assumption can totally be questioned. I have an intuition for how it's possible that the axiom of choice is false. If you try to break down everything and ask yourself why something is true, then according to what you accept as proof, you can't proof anything. What will then come naturally is to not overthink and not worry about whether something is really true or not and assert what

Comment: ever you feel like asserting and be like "Whether it's true or not, this is what I want to assert is true." It's almost like you can just decide how your imaginary world goes. You may be thinking, "Surely, I can prove the distance formula." The truth is that you're making assumptions about what properties the distance formula satisfies. You can define the distance formula in one way that will satisfy those properties or you can define it another way to be like hyperbolic geometry. When you use different methods of calculations, you get different results. If you decide to seek a definition of

Comment: distance that satisfies those properties and find one and prove that it satisfies those properties, and then after that, you decide to use another method of calculation where you use only your previous computed result that the distance formula satisfies those properties and then use a certain method of deduction, you derive the result of what precisely the distance formula is. Maybe it really is the case that no theory at all is disprovable including the theory that the ordinal number $\epsilon_0$ doesn't exist at all. Then if you use a long slow careful debating process, then you might gain

Comment: an understanding of a theory where $\epsilon_0$ exists as well as a theory where $\epsilon_0$ doesn't exist and then you will derive the final conclusion that it's possible that $\epsilon_0$ doesn't exist. Even if the theory that $\epsilon_0$ doesn't exist is true, that doesn't mean you can't have a feel for a false theory that $\epsilon_0$ does exist. Although your brain may end up determining the truth, its method of doing so is through a continuous slow hyperaware thinking process of debating options and having a feel for them and ending up at the conclusion that maybe $\epsion_0$ doesn't

Comment: exist and continuously nonstop having you mind wander and explore so many theories all the time including false ones, yet reliably get the correct conclusion with a bit of time every time through the wandering mind process for some complex reason. The brain is like a Conway's game of life. It can emulate all kinds of formal systems. Even if one formal system believed to be true proves that something satisfying certain properties doesn't exist, it's always possible to weaken the system to prove even less and then add on other rules of inference to prove things that are disprovable in the

Comment: original system including the existence of something proven by the original system not to exist. Maybe your brain is doing something like like when you form the intuition that $\epsilon_0$ exists. Even if $\epsilon_0$ doesn't exist, the formal system that proves its exists. You may be like, "Surely, each sentence represents a real existing statement." The statement it represents may be true but that doesn't mean there exists anything satisfying the claimed properties of that statement. Maybe what does exist is not the statement itself but its formal representation. Then there is no such thing

Comment: as a sentence that refers to $\epsilon_0$ or a statement specifically because $\epsilon_0$ and statements don't exist but what there is such as thing as is a sentence that asserts that $\epsilon_0$ exists and a sentence that asserts that statements exist. On the other hand, sentences totally exist. They're just a formal representation. I totally reject the unlearning theory of the brain. In the past, people thought the brain became hardwired in adulthood. If the unlearning theory were true, that would mean we got hard wired in adulthood. I think it's very possible to have connections for

Comment: perceiving untrue theories. For example, there was a show called "Kate plus 8." It used to be called "John and Kate plus 8" but later, John divorced and just Kate was looking after all 8 of her kids who were older twins who were girls and younger sextuplets who were 3 boys and 3 girls. I think one of the older girls "Maddie" moved and at first, Kate felt like she missed her but then she decided to just pretend Maddie was continuously staying in her room just like she was before. This contradicts the unlearning theory.

Comment: I cannot figure out what your question is ever after you accepted an answer. I'm kind of curious what your question really was. So for example, if you happened to have the right type of question, if you learned that deciding that what your own state of mind right now is all you need to know, that would be a satisfactory answer for you and then me learning that that was the resolution to your problem would be satisfactory for me. However, it's okay. I don't really need to know what your question was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked, "what if?" The answer is this:

If we were not actually individuals but were actors in a sophisticated play, then like the actors in plays and movies who shoot each other, lie, cheat and steal... who perform death-defying stunts or slaughter masses of innocent people, we would not reap any of the longer-term consequences of our actions but might get a "best supporting actor" award if we showed enough true-seeming emotion while we did stuff.

Give it a test!  Steal a chocolate bar from a gas station and see what happens!

Comment: Answer of a person who's apperceptions are complicated by all sorts of interesting ideas. +1

Answer (score 4):

The OP asks the following question:

> What if everything were fake?

This would mean that our belief in the reality around us is false. It would mean that we do not have true beliefs. We make enough mistakes to know that our beliefs need not be true.

When we think *everything* is fake we doubt our ability to achieve true beliefs. In such an extreme case even the belief that everything we believe is fake may not be a true belief. This also seems possible, because sometimes we get things right, that is, we don't make mistakes.

This kind of doubting is called "epistemic self-doubt". [Sherrilyn Roush describes this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemic-self-doubt/) as a "level-splitting state" where we are unable to fit our beliefs with our beliefs about our beliefs.

Furthermore, should we claim that everything is *fake* we are taking a pessimistic view of reality. Saying something is fake implies that our experience is not really as good as we think it is.

Since that pessimistic belief about our beliefs might itself be false, we need to also consider the optimistic alternative: *What we experience might be better than we believe it to be.* When we experience reality we might be only looking at the dark shadows playing on the wall of Plato's cave. What we experience might be good in a way we can only begin to imagine whether or not it is a single person's mind generating it.

---

Roush, Sherrilyn, "Epistemic Self-Doubt", The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Winter 2017 Edition), Edward N. Zalta (ed.), URL = https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/win2017/entries/epistemic-self-doubt/.

Answer (score 3):

If our minds, consciousnesses, capacities for awareness -- are generated from and in communion with the source known to us as the universal and eternal mind (i.e. God), then we should consider ourselves of a divine nature: 'born of God'; although not necessarily 'little gods' or God's equals. The physical [world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World) we inhabit tends to make us feel mentally confused and alienated to the point where many of us are easily deluded into thinking this is all there is. Many become obsessed with materialism and forget or rebel against from whom we originated, leading to confusion over the apparent conflict between immortal mind and physical decline and death. We don't fully understand how the idealistic, imaginative mind relates to concrete reality.

I've lately reached the conclusion that our [brains](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-brain-a-receiver-a-transmitter-both-or-neither) are actually [receivers](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/01/140122133713.htm) for consciousness, and that consciousness is actually a form of divine [communication](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/theory-consciousness/201801/consciousness-attention-and-communication). Therefore, obviously imperfections, injuries, or defects of the brain may be a hindrance. I also note that human IQ across all demographics declines in children between the ages of 7 and 17. To me this is indicative of [the limitations presented by material *reality* upon the human mind.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20349385)

[image: Intelligence]

So the answer to your question, *Is anything real?*, is: Yes. Everything, including consciousness -- is real.

**References:**

- Wikipedia
- Quora
- Science Daily
- Psychology Today
- Pub Med (US National Center for Biotechnology Information)
- Youtube (image of IQ chart)

Answer (score 1):

If you are quite sure about this, you need not be worried about anything.  If you are **always** aware that everything (including your body, mind, ego etc.) is fake, nothing will worry you.  Since you feel all relations are also fake, you feel you are liberated from all bondage.  So you may sit self contented.

To know more about the Ultimate Reality, See:

> **Brahman as a metaphysical concept**
>
> Brahman is the key metaphysical concept in various schools of Hindu
>   philosophy. It is the theme in its diverse discussions to the two
>   central questions of metaphysics: what is ultimately real, and are
>   there principles applying to everything that is real?[63] Brahman is
>   the ultimate "eternally, constant" reality, while the observed
>   universe is a different kind of reality but one which is "temporary,
>   changing" Maya in various orthodox Hindu schools. Maya pre-exists and
>   co-exists with **Brahman—the Ultimate Reality**, The Highest Universal,
>   the Cosmic Principles.[64]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman

Don't worry thinking that nothing is real.  The real thing is nothing other than your true nature.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aham_Brahmasmi

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like solipsism and all serious philosophy dismiss solipsism as not worth thinking about.

The only reason to take it seriously is because quite a few people get seduced into thinking about solipsism and then it's a matter of pointing out why its a philosophy of no value.

Comment: There aren't many solipsists around but all serious philosophers think very hard about why Solipsism and Scepticism are unfalsifiable and what it means for the nature of Reality. Less serious philosophers jump to conclusions.